# Qt. Как зафиксировать положение объекта при компоновке

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, margin, отступы

В общем я делаю симулятор MacOS Monterey на Qt (небольшой, ради интереса и для практики). К MenuBar приставляю пружину вертикальную. И проблема в том, что оно отходит от краев

P.S: Высоту я сделал правильную, поставив мин. и макс. значение. Мне нужно, чтобы оно только в ширину отходило, ну типа на весь экран, независимо от разрешения (Qt Designer)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы работаете в QtCreator, то надо настроить отступы для соответствующего лейаута на соответствующем виджете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если руками, то использовать вот эту функцию [QLayout::setContentsMargin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)